# ArrayList does not satisfy generic serializable list type

Tags: java, generics, java-5

Given the following java code:

```
public static <I extends Serializable, L extends List<I> & Serializable> L getList() {
    return new ArrayList<I>(); // <-- Compile error
}
```

Given that `ArrayList` do extend both `Serializable` and `List`, why does it produce a compile error?

`Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.ArrayList<I>', required: 'L'`

Comment: Because your method says it will return an `L`, not an `ArrayList<I>`. `L` is a type parameter, so the caller gets to specify the type argument. For example, suppose they call `<String, LinkedList<String>> getList()` and assign the result to a `LinkedList<String>`... how would you expect that to work if you're returning an `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JonSkeet. How it is then possible to return a generic serializable list?

Comment: Well we don't have any of the context here - do you *have* to use that method signature? How are you expecting this to be called? It's been a while since I've done Java, but I don't know of any way of saying "I will return something that implements these two interfaces".

Comment: @JonSkeet I added a possible solution to my question. What is your opinion?

Comment: Well, that works but means you can't use any existing classes. If that's okay for you, then fine - we don't really know the requirements. I would suggest you add your possible solution as an answer rather than leaving it in the question though.

Comment: @JonSkeet done. Thanks for the hint and for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
public interface SerializableList<T> extends List<T>, Serializable {
}

public class SerializableArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements SerializableList<T> {
    public SerializableArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
    }

    public SerializableArrayList() {
    }

    public SerializableArrayList(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        super(c);
    }
}
```

Then whenever I need a `Serializable` `List` type, I can use the `SerializableList` interface and its implementation `SerializableArrayList`